Some questions on syntax
In an italian translation of Platon's Criton an ancient text's line is translated as
Mi meraviglio che la guardia della prigione abbia acconsentito ad aprirti.
I have some questions:
A. What is mi syntactically? Isn' it sufficient to say [io] meraviglio che... (I wonder that..)?
B. How do we call the subordinated sentence che...aprirti (in greek we would call it εἰδική)? Which categories of subordinated clauses do we have in italian?
C. Which are the criteria of using the prepositions per, da, a(d), etc. before an infinitive? (I mean why to use e.g. per and not ad etc.)

Someone should write a complete and definitive answer about pronominal intransitive verbs in Italian, since the topic seems to return often.

The verb being used here is meravigliarsi, not meravigliare.
